# jQuery and Firebug

Tags: jquery, firebug

I am using [jQuery's cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin, and found that I can call up the default for "speed" by typing this into Firebug's console:

> $.fn.cycle.defaults.speed
>
> > >>> 1000

I would like to know how to call up the override I have for speed (I would like to reuse it later):

> $('.xxx').cycle({
>   speed:  1700
>   });

If you have the answer, please let me know the steps taken to figure it out so I can understand Firebug better.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the code and it doesn't appear that the calculated options are exposed anywhere.  They're captured as a local variable in several functions after they are built, but I don't know how you would get at them.  You could set breakpoints in the relevant parts of the (unminified) cycle code with Firebug and inspect the values, but I don't think you can get at them programmatically.  In any event it would be easier to store them in a variable, then use that variable in the options that you provide.

```
var cycleSpeed = 1700;

$('.klass').cycle({ speed: cycleSpeed });
```